# Where to find Google Maps Current Location API?

Tags: vb.net, google-maps

I am developing desktop application and need Google Maps API which will detect user current location and get their coordinates. Once I detect their location I will pass those coordinates to geocode:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=[coordinates]&sensor=false

What would be Google Maps API URL for current location detection? Could somebody point me in the right direction?

Note I am developing my desktop app in vb.NET

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Comment: Will it work in vb.net?